# RFID RC522 card reader project(servo, buzzer, two led) with FreeRTOS

Tags: arduino-uno

So I wrote simple code which turns on led, buzzes and rotates servo motor when card readed. It works normally. But I want buzz, rotate and on off functions to work asynchorous. I will paste the code which I tried to apply freertos. Any help is appreciated!

```
void loop() {
 if (!mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
 return;
}

if (!mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    return;
}

for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
  card_ID += mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];
}

if (card_ID == rfid) {

  //
  // I want to create async tasks here...
  //
  buzz(750, 1000); // task 1

  green_on();      //
  delay(1500);     // task 2
  off();           // 

  rotate();        // task 3

}
//Serial.print(card_ID);
else {
  red_on();
  delay(700);
  off();
  red_on();
  delay(700);
  off();

  buzz();
}

card_ID = "";
}`
```

my freertos applied code is this. i will just paste the rotate function of all task functions for showing purposes:

```
void setup() {
// some code here  - inits and other things
  xTaskCreate(Main,(const portCHAR *) "Main", 128, NULL, 1, NULL );
  vTaskStartScheduler();
}


void Main(void *pvParameters) {
(void) pvParameters;

for(;;) {
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
      return;
    }

    // Select one of the cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
      return;
    }

    //mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));

    for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
     card_ID += mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];
   }

   if(card_ID==rfid){
    xTaskCreate(Buzz,(const portCHAR *) "Buzz", 128, NULL, 2, NULL );
    xTaskCreate(GreenLed,(const portCHAR *) "GreenLed", 128, NULL, 3, NULL );
    xTaskCreate(Rotate,(const portCHAR *) "Rotate", 128, NULL, 4, NULL );


   }
   //Serial.print(card_ID);



   else {
     xTaskCreate(RedLed,(const portCHAR *) "RedLed", 128, NULL, 2, NULL );
     xTaskCreate(Buzz,(const portCHAR *) "Buzz", 128, NULL, 3, NULL );
   }

   card_ID="";
 }
}

void Rotate(void *pvParameters) {
(void) pvParameters;

 for(;;) {
    for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
    // in steps of 1 degree
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                      // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
}
    for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
      myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
      vTaskDelay(15 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
    }
  vTaskDelay(1);
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean by `work asynchorous`? ... please provide a clear description of the desired behavior

Comment: sorry if I'm mistaken, I am trying to say that I want three tasks to work at the same time, I also have written it in first code, line 12